# Inherit from BasicObject to Increase Performance

Tags: ruby

I am investigating whether I can increase performance by having my PageObjects class inherit from BasicObject. The rationale is that BasicObjects has far fewer built in methods than a regular object. However, I am running into this error:

```
 <class:PageObject>': uninitialized constant PageObject::ENV (NameError)
 Did you mean?  ENV
```

I've tried various ways to import env.rb (BasicObject doesn't have this built in) but I keep getting errors. Here's one attempt at importing it.

```
 class PageObject < BasicObject
   include ENV
   def initialize
     home_dir = ENV["HOME"]
     load_page_object_file(open("# 
    {home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/shared_page_objects.yml"))
    load_page_object_file(open("#{home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/urls.yml"))
    load_page_object_file('spec/support/page_objects.yml')
   end
 end
```

How do I import class methods from rubystubs library?

Comment: `ENV` is a class so you can't include it, call it like this `::ENV["HOME"]`

Comment: Are you sure this is even worthwhile? `BasicObject` is more about namespace pollution than performance and you're already opening files (which you could do by hand with `File`), parsing YAML, ...

Comment: I'm not sure but I can post results once I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what performance objectives you have, which using `BasicObject` can solve, but these are the *instance methods* available in `Object`, which are not available in `BasicObject`.

```
Object.instance_methods - BasicObject.instance_methods
#=>  [:instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :public_send, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :remove_instance_variable, :define_singleton_method, :instance_variable_set, :extend, :to_enum, :enum_for, :<=>, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :respond_to?, :freeze, :inspect, :object_id, :send, :display, :to_s, :nil?, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_defined?]
```

Since you want few methods from `Object`, instead of using `BasicObject`, you can create a new class and undefine the methods you do not need.

```
class MyBasicObject
  instance_methods.each do |m|
    next if [:instance_of?, :is_a?].include?(m)
    undef_method m
  end
end
class PageObject < MyBasicObject
  def initialize
     home_dir = ::ENV["HOME"]
     load_page_object_file(open("# 
    {home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/shared_page_objects.yml"))
    load_page_object_file(open("#{home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/urls.yml"))
    load_page_object_file('spec/support/page_objects.yml')
  end
end
```

However, if your objective is to just make `open` work, please note that `open` is a method of `Kernel` module and is not an instance method of `Object`. You can simplify your particular case with `BasicObject` by `include`ing `Kernel` module explicitly in your class.

```
 class PageObject < BasicObject
   include ::Kernel
   def initialize
     home_dir = ::ENV["HOME"]
     load_page_object_file(open("# 
    {home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/shared_page_objects.yml"))
    load_page_object_file(open("#{home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/urls.yml"))
    load_page_object_file('spec/support/page_objects.yml')
   end
 end
```

PS: Thanks to @anthony for pointing to correct usage of `::ENV`

Comment: Just like `::ENV` you have to write `include ::Kernel`

Comment: Thanks. I was running in `irb` for this, and forgot about that case :D

Comment: If `Kernel#open` is the only objective then `define_method(:open,&::Kernel.instance_method(:open).bind(self))` would work.

Comment: @kiddorails Can you walk me through the meta programming in MyBasicObject?

Comment: @engineersmnky or just `define_method(:open, &::Kernel.method(:open))`. Edit: Just saw your edit to reflect the same :)

Comment: @kiddorails I forgot that `Kernel` exposed its methods as `module_functions` +1

Comment: @CaptainKidd `instance_methods` gives the list of instance methods(included inherited) in that class, in `MyBasicObject`, I'm iterating on them, and calling `undef_method` on the ones I do not need. `undef_method` will then _undefine_ those methods for that class, making it _lightweight_.

Comment: I am getting error undefined method for define_method.

Comment: @kiddorails Ok I tried it like that.. Now I get this error: 'code' An error occurred while 
Failure/Error:
  load_page_object_file(open("#
    {home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/shared_page_objects.yml"))

Errno::EINVAL:
  Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - #
      {home_dir}/code/automate_shared/lib/shared_page_objects.yml
# ./spec/support/page_object.rb:12:in `initialize'

Comment: that's your code issue. this is the error generated by `open` with whatever you are trying to open. Please debug futher, that is out of scope of this question. :) Hope this helps